# Catalyst: Passing query param to a "forward" call

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a Catalyst Controller that responds to arguments in the usual way (`/endpoint/foo/bar`), but also takes a query parameter for a security token. How can I set the value of the parameter before I initiate a `forward` call to this Controller? It doesn't let me assign to `$c->req->param('token')`.

(It's not possible to rewrite the controller to accept the token as an argument instead of a parameter.)

Comment: You are saying you want to modify the request, so you can use this 3rd party Controller correctly? Because it doesn't take Controller args. Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly, but it more or less needs to work this way. It does take Controller args but it also takes a single query parameter. What I actually need to do is initiate a new request for this Controller; I will have both the arguments and the value for the query parameter and I need to get these to the Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$c->req->param('token')` is not an LValue, so you cannot *assign* to it. Instead, you need [to pass in the value](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Request#$req-%3Eparam).

```
$c->req->param('token', 1);
```

This behaviour is sort of documented:

> Like CGI, and unlike earlier versions of Catalyst, passing multiple
>   arguments to this method, like this:
>
> ```
>  $c->request->param( 'foo', 'bar', 'gorch', 'quxx' );
> ```
>
> will set the parameter foo to the multiple values bar, gorch and quxx.
>   Previously this would have added bar as another value to foo (creating
>   it if it didn't exist before), and quxx as another value for gorch.

Consider this demo:

```perl
package MyApp::Controller::Root;
use base 'Catalyst::Controller';
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');

sub default : Path {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->req->param('foo', 1);
    $c->forward('bar');
}

sub bar : Path('foo') {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    if ($c->req->param('foo')) {
        $c->res->body("Secret param set!\n");
    }
    else {
        $c->res->body("Hello World\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah, wonderful, thank you. I did see that section of the docs, but it was not only confusing, but littered with warnings about how this is unsafe and will be deprecated, so I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: @user1235777 it's not a great solution, but it has to do I guess.